# OdbcDataReader hangs on long query

Tags: c#

I am trying to extract data from iSeries database and create Excel report from the data. I am using C# and EPPlus library to do this. Below is my code that works to generate the repor:

```
queryString = @"SELECT oacspo, pldesc, obivdt, oainno, obitno, obitd1, obitd2, obqtsh, obaslp, oblnam
              FROM myLib.hshed 
              LEFT JOIN myLib.cusms 
                ON oacsno = cmcsno
              LEFT JOIN myLib.hsdet
                ON oahssq = obhssq
              LEFT JOIN myLib.itemctrl
                ON obitno = icitno
              LEFT JOIN myLib.plinesj
                ON icline = plcode
              WHERE (oaipdt BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND icdlcu = 'Y' AND oacsno = ?
              ORDER BY pldesc, oainno, obitno";
          command = new OdbcCommand(queryString, connection);
          command.CommandTimeout = 0;
          parameter = command.Parameters.Add("@DateStart", OdbcType.Int);
          parameter.Value = startDate;
          parameter = command.Parameters.Add("@DateEnd", OdbcType.Int);
          parameter.Value = endDate;
          parameter = command.Parameters.Add("@CustomerNo", OdbcType.Int);
          parameter.Value = custNo;
          OdbcDataReader readerRpt = command.ExecuteReader();
```

That one runs ok but when I add one more specification to the WHERE clause (to narrow down to a specific department), I got an error:

```
WHERE (oaipdt BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND icdlcu = 'Y' AND oacsno = ? AND icline = 'O'
```

> Error: ERROR [HY000] [IBM][iSeries Access ODBC Driver][DB2 UDB]SQL0666
>   - SQL query exceeds specified time limit or storage limit.

I did some research and changed the CommandTimeout properties to 0

```
command.CommandTimeout = 0;
```

But as a result the program just hang when I execute the line

```
OdbcDataReader readerRpt = command.ExecuteReader();
```

There is not a lot of data (about 1,000 rows) so I do not think that it exceeds storage limit. Or does it based on how many characters I can put in the query string? (which means I cannot have a long SQL statement).

Some directions on how to get this to work is really appreciated. Thank you

Comment: The report may be only returning 1000 lines but the joins could be a problem if the column you joining on is not correctly index eg.  when joining to another table to filter by department, there may be a table scan occurring on a million rows because of incorrect indexing... or summing like that. - check out the column used in the join for the department...

Comment: Beat me too it Quinton. What size tables are we talking about here?

Comment: itemctrl only has 6000 rows and plines just 12 rows. the hshed and hesdet have tons of rows. Once I took out the join to plines, the query runs fine but I do not have department description. I have already changed the code so that it looks at the dept code to put the department description in Excel instead of querying it